# Why is 'nextDateAfterDate' function not working as expected?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I have the following code in a XCode Playground:

```
let currentDate = NSDate()

var starttime = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().nextDateAfterDate(currentDate, matchingUnit: NSCalendarUnit.Minute, value: 15, options: NSCalendarOptions.MatchNextTime)
```

If currentDate is "2016-01-03 03:57 +0100" starttime is correctly set to "Jan 3, 2016, 4:15 AM", but if currentDate is "2016-01-03 03:56 +0100" starttime ist incorrectly set to "Jan 4, 2016, 12:00 AM". I can't figure out whats wrong. Do I overlook something?

Comment: I don't have an answer but I do confirm the results with snippet: https://gitlab.com/snippets/12822

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not explain the unexpected behaviour, but setting the matching options to

```
[.MatchNextTime, .MatchStrictly]
```

solves the problem and gives correct results in all my tests.

`.MatchStrictly` is documented as

> Specifies that the operation should travel as far forward or backward as necessary looking for a match.

Comment: Thank you, I tested it and also using only `NSCalendarOptions.MatchStrictly` gives me correct results.
Nevertheless I sent a bugreport to Apple, because of the strange behavior of the `.MatchNextTime`-Option.